# unix: find strings that match those in a list and then modify last character of the string

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Let's say I have the following in a file:

```
AAA|population:A1
BBB|population:A1
CCC|population:A2
DDD|population:A1
```

And I want to change the lines beginning with BBB and DDD so that the file becomes:

```
AAA|population:A1
BBB|population:A2
CCC|population:A2
DDD|population:A2
```

I would like to create a variable with all the strings to find (in this case BBB and DDD) and then change only the last character (in this case "1") of all lines that match that string.

The variable would look like:

```
myList='BBB|DDD'
```

And then I should be able to use awk for the replacement but I don't know how to replace only the last character of the matches.

Comment: A better approach is to create a file say `file.sed` that contains 1 line for each search string with the corresponding replacement command such as `/^BBB|/{s/.$/2/}` then run `sed -i -f file.sed inputfile.txt`.

Comment: What is the way you want to `change the last character` In this example 1's  become 2. Are the last characters always 1 and you always want to make them 2? Is the last character always a digit and you want to increment it ? Any other way to describe your modification ?

Comment: Hakan Baba: The last character will always be a number in this case but not always a "1". I will not necessarily be incrementing it. Happy to have a more generalized answer to search for matches to any string in a list, then substitute only the last character on lines with match to that string.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
R=2; myList="BBB DDD"; matches=$(echo $myList | sed 's/\ /\\|/g'); sed  -i  "s/\($matches\)\(.*\).$/\1\2$R/g" file1
```

Given the file is named `file1`. You can pass the character you want to have in the same command line in `R`.
`myList` should be a single space delimited of strings you want to match

This modifies file1 in place.

---

Diff of the file1 before and after looks like

```
 $ diff file1 file1_old
2c2
< BBB|population:A2
---
> BBB|population:A1
4c4
< DDD|population:A2
---
> DDD|population:A1
```

Comment: I could not get this to work. I really need the list to match to be a variable. The real files that I'm working on require that I search for a large number of strings from a large number of files...

Comment: @user2414840 I have modified my answer to accept the myList as an input variable. Does this work for you ? If this also does not work, can you give more information how it does not work for you ?

Comment: Thanks Hakan Baba, I figured out that I needed a -E option on my version of sed. I posted my final answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ myList='BBB|DDD'; i=2; sed -ri "s/(($myList).*).$/\1$i/" file
```

Brief explanation,

- `-r`: the option for extended regular expressions, so some escape character may be omitted
- Mind to use the double quotes to expand the shell variable `$myList` and `$i`
- You may add your desired string the `$myList`

Comment: This didn't work for me. The -r option gives me "sed: illegal option -- r" error. I'm working on a mac. Without the -ri options (I don't yet care about saving the file until I see the correct result in standard output), I get the error "\1 not defined in the RE". Is there something I need to change in the syntax for a mac?

Answer (score 0):

My final answer is as follows. Assuming file name is "test"

```
myList='BBB|DDD'
R='2'
sed -E "s/(($myList).*).$/\1$R/" test
```

Gives the desired result.

```
AAA|population:A1
BBB|population:A2
CCC|population:A2
DDD|population:A2
```